# Saving Changes to Database Using LINQ and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this code. The code will find the correct log but won't save any changes back to the database. How would I get it to save?

```
var query = from log in db.Logs
            where log.LogID == id
            select log;

foreach (Log log in query)
{
    log.DateTimeResolved = System.DateTime.Now;
    db.Entry(query).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{ }

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: Don't use an empty `catch` block - any error you get is being ignored.

Comment: `db.Entry(log)` but Still, you should not need that.

Comment: The assumption is that you are throwing an error, catching it, and discarding it.  What, if anything, is the value of `e` when you debug this?

Comment: Does this go in the foreach loop?

Comment: You shouldn't have to set the state to modified.  The state tracking should do that automatically.

Comment: I suspect the erroneous `db.Entry(query)` will blow up and give an exception, skipping saving.

Comment: No but db.SaveChanges() thorws an error

Comment: Show the full error details including any inner exceptions and enumerating any of the validation errors. I suspect once you see the real message, the solution should be apparent.

Comment: InnerException is null. There isn't anything I can see apparent from the details

Answer (score 1):

Well it's hard to say since you're ignoring any exception that is thrown, but this looks suspect:

```
foreach (Log log in query)
{
    log.DateTimeResolved = System.DateTime.Now;
    db.Entry(query).State = EntityState.Modified;
}            ^---  should be "log" instead of "query"?
```

My guess is that since `Entry()` takes an object it *compiles* but at runtime you're getting an error and ignoring it.  As stated in the comments, you should not need to explicitly set the state to `Modified` since you're modifying the entity directly.  I think you just need:

```
foreach (Log log in query)
{
    log.DateTimeResolved = System.DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: db.SaveChanges() throws Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There was a Required field in my Log entity class causing the problem. Though why would it need to set this again if i'm just updating and not adding?